# How to apply pagespeed insights results

Tags: performance, coverage.py, pagespeed-insights

Well, I trying establish a [web page](https://fixaj.com/) with a wordpress and GoDaddy hosting. I want to make fast web page, because people says fast web pages appear on first line at Google (as specially mobile web page speed is very important people says). So want to make very fast web page but my level of knowledge is not very advanced, I progress by learning.

If I test my web page with Insights, mine mobile score is about 60-70. If I read reports of Insights there are lots of improvements links appear at blow. I want to learn how to fix that. If you help me make an example, I will do the others myself.

[image]

If we start at first problem which is [/css?family=…(fonts.googleapis.com)](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik%3A300%2Cregular%2C500%2C700%2C900%7CRoboto%3A100%2C200%2C300%2C400%2C500%2C600%2C700%2C800%2C900&subset=latin%2Clatin-ext%2Ccyrillic%2Ccyrillic-ext&display=swap) this problem seen below of "Eliminate resources that prevent rendering" topic. So how to fix it. What should I do?

[image]

Also at the "covorage" tab there are some source codes are seen and it is not using. For example I am not using easy-sheare plugin (secong row at the image) at homepage.

How to remove safely that codes from home page. If I can learn how one is made, I can correct the others myself.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are running into is something I have seen over and over again. GoDaddy and Wordpress sites generally are bloated and perform poorly.

Here are some tips to improve your speed & get a better PS ranking.

1. Hosting: Do you need to be on Godaddy? I have seen this time and time again. Most websites on GD are SLOW. GD is good for domain registration, not for hosting. Most non-tech folks do not know any better. Try using Amazon Lightsail, AWS-S3, Google Firebase, or Netlify. They all offer much faster page loads by reducing initial server response time. And they are surprisingly simple to learn and deploy.
2. CDN: You must use a content-distribution-network (CDN). Check out Cloudfront. They offer a free tier that works quite well.
3. Wordpress: This is your real issue. Wordpress is neither easy to build nor easy to maintain. You need multiple plugins to make the site perform. Best you build your own. If you have to be on Wordpress checkout image optimizers, minifiers, and cache plugins. Gumlet, WP Rocket, Shortpixel are quite popular to improve speed.